# Have Custom Style Change Based On My AppTheme Style Selection

Tags: android, themes

I have an app for which I want to provide a light and a dark theme.

For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    ...
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dark">
    ...
</style>
```

I also have a custom style that specifies a background to be applied to anything that uses it:

```
<style name="MyCustomViewBackground">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/half_alpha_white_rounded_background</item>
</style>
```

How do I arrange things such that my MyCustomViewBackground style specifies one background for my AppTheme.Light style (half_alpha_white_rounded_background), and a different background for my AppTheme.Dark style (half_alpha_dark_rounded_background)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (did not test):

attrs.xml

```
<resources>
        <attr name="customViewBackground" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="MyCustomViewBackground">
    ...
    <item name="android:background">?attr/customViewBackground</item>
    ...
</style>
```

themes.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    ...
    <item name="customViewBackground">@drawable/half_alpha_white_rounded_background</item>
    ...
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dark">
    ...
    <item name="customViewBackground">@drawable/half_alpha_dark_rounded_background</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This looks promising.  I'll test tonight and let you know.

Comment: This worked.  The key piece I was missing was defining a custom attribute with which I could switch out the background I wanted based on the Theme.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cool stuff, glad I could help. Remember to mark the answer as accepted so it doesn't drift off in no answer land.